# Print output from Solve in a custom format

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
Solve[{A + B = 3, 2 A + B = 5}, {A, B}]
```

evaluates to `A = 2, B = 1`.

How can I `Print` the result like this

`W = 2 + 1 * Sinx`

Answer (score 0):

Study https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html and then try

```
Print[W==A+B*Sinx/.Solve[{A+B==3, 2A+B==5}, {A,B}][[1]]]
```

which prints

```
W==2+Sinx
```

because Mathematica automatically simplifies 1*Sinx to Sinx